# Pythonic way of creating 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 2d

I have a function `gen()` which returns a numpy array of `nElements` number of floats. I'm looking for a more Pythonic (one liner?) way to do the following:

```
a = zeros((nSamples, nElements))
for i in xrange(nSamples):
     a[i,:] = gen()
```

This is one way to do it:

```
a = array([gen() for i in xrange(nSamples)]).reshape((nSamples, nElements))
```

But it understandably is a bit slower on account of not pre-allocating the numpy array:

```
import time
from numpy import *

nSamples  = 100000
nElements = 100

start = time.time()
a = array([gen() for i in xrange(nSamples)]).reshape((nSamples, nElements))
print (time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
a = zeros((numSamples, nElements))
for i in xrange(numSamples):
    a[i,:] = gen()
print (time.time() - start)
```

**Output:**

```
1.82166719437
0.502261161804
```

So, is there a way to achieve the same one-liner while keeping the preallocated array for speed?

Thanks,
-Nate

Comment: I'm no great guru of pythonicity, but I would use empty() rather than zeros() to save time, avoiding one useless pass over the entire array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe this will do what you want:

```
a = vstack([ gen() for _ in xrange(nSamples) ])
```

as i don't have access to your `gen` function, i can't do timing tests.  also, this (as well as your one-liner) are not as memory-friendly as your for loop version.  the one-liners store all `gen()` outputs and then construct the array, whereas the for loop only needs to have one `gen()` in memory at a time (along with the numpy array).

Comment: Thanks for the input! This is indeed a bit slower than the for loop, but it works well for my purposes.

Answer (score 9):

This may not answer your question directly, but since you mentioned *Pythonic* in the title... Please understand that *Pythonic* isn't necessarily a "one-liner" or the most clever and short (keystroke-wise) way of doing something. Quite the contrary - Pythonic code strives for clarity.

In the case of your code, I find:

```
a = zeros((nSamples, nElements))
for i in xrange(nSamples):
     a[i,:] = gen()
```

Much clearer than:

```
a = array([gen() for i in xrange(nSamples)]).reshape((nSamples, nElements))
```

Hence I wouldn't say the second one is more Pythonic. Probably less so.